# How to create a loop that will show column coverage by row in R

Tags: r, loops

I am currently working on a project where we are looking at data in a country-year format. That is each country and year combination is a unique case. I want to create a loop that goes through every variable and runs counts by each year. I can currently do this for each individual variable by using data.table in R. For example:

```
DT[, list(total = sum(v_23_27 !=99999)), by = ID_year]'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am looking for non-NA cases in order to check the coverage of the dataset. Example data below:

```
Year Country Var1 Var2 
2001 Canada  NA   NA
2001 USA     .32  NA
2001 Sweden  NA   1
2002 Canada  .1   NA
2002 USA    .32   1
2002 Sweden  NA   1
```

Comment: Counts of what?

Comment: Please add an example of the data please.

Comment: This is currently unclear. Perhaps you're looking for `DT[, list(total = sum(v_23_27 !=99999)), by = list(ID_year, ID_country)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `dplyr`. Here's a version that would count non-NA values for each column each year:

```
# make toy data
set.seed(20912)
df <- data.frame(country = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
                 year = rep(seq(1995,1999), 2),
                 var1 = rnorm(10, 100, 20),
                 var2 = sample(c("lo", "hi", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

# create function for counting non-NA values
noNAsum <- function(x) { sum(!is.na(x)) }

# group the data by year and then apply the function to each column of interest
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(noNAsum), var1:var2)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
   year  var1  var2
  <int> <int> <int>
1  1995     2     1
2  1996     2     2
3  1997     2     0
4  1998     2     2
5  1999     2     2
```

If you want to use different rules for different columns, you could expand the call to `summarize` to accommodate that, e.g.:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(var1 = sum(var1 > 100),
            var2 = sum(!is.na(var2)))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
   year  var1  var2
  <int> <int> <int>
1  1995     1     1
2  1996     1     2
3  1997     0     0
4  1998     1     2
5  1999     0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that can help you look at metadata of your dataset http://www.bytefold.com/generate-metadata-for-a-dataset-in-r/

you can try this, it gives basic info about your dataset.